# [ios]Archive files uploaded from App Store Connect are not visible

Tags: ios, release, archive

I created an archive for app release.

But no matter how much time passes, nothing appears in the build window.

What should I do

+)I have a Team and make a identifier, certificate for team.

I even uploaded the archive file successfully.

But in App store connect, Nothing is shown.
[image]
[image]

Comment: please check your email if you are not seeing the build on the test flight maybe apple rejected your archive. This happens sometimes some pods need permissions and you forgot to add those in your plist. check your mail they will tell you exactly what you are missing

Comment: after check my email, I found my app have an issue with UIWebview, and plist that missing value. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen if your uploaded archive couldn't pass through the initial processing of the build that occurs as soon as it is uploaded.

I once got stuck with this because my app had some legacy code that was using UIWebview which is now deprecated.

You'll always receive some comment from apple if this happens (through email).

Comment: I found my app have an issue with UIWebview. You're right.
I'don know apple send a email about a archive issue before your answer.
Thank you!